# Background coloring in R Markdown (html) with KableExtra based on multiple conditions (problems with NA) (R)

Tags: r, background-color, kable

I would like to background-color the values of the corresponding matrix based on several conditions.

[image]

The conditions are the following:

1. X > 0.5 -> green
2. X < 0.5 -> red
3. X = 0.5 -> no coloring

**Input**:

```
matrix %>%
    mutate_at(vars(BM), ~ cell_spec(
        ., "html", 
        background = ifelse(. > 0.5, "lightgreen", ifelse(. < 0.50, "tomato"))
        )) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(COM), ~ cell_spec(
        ., "html", 
        background = ifelse(. > 0.5, "lightgreen", ifelse(. < 0.50, "tomato"))
        )) %>%
    kable(format = "html", escape = FALSE, digits = 2) %>%
    kable_styling("striped", full_width = FALSE)
```

The above code works fine for column "BM and "COM" as no NAs are apparent.

[image]

However, as soon as I add column "CC" the following error message occurs.

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `CC`.
x missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
i Input `CC` is `(structure(function (..., .x = ..1, .y = ..2, . = ..1) ...`.
i The error occured in group 2: CNTRY = "MX":
```

**Problems to solve**

1. How can I work around the NAs so that I can color all the columns?
2. The rounding seems not to work in the colored matrix. Why? How can I work around that?

Any help is very appreciated!